# Inner height of an AngularJS element that contains an img tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get the full height of an AngularJS div that contains an img tag w/o luck. Since the image hasn't rendered yet, sometimes my call to el[0].offsetHeight works and sometimes it doesn't so just assuming the offsetHeight doesn't have the img doesn't work.

What are my options?

Here's my code:

```
angular.module('itemApp').directive('itemRender', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'tmpl/item.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, el) {
            //turning off angularjs dirty checking
            $timeout(init, 0, true);

            //init
            function init() {
                var arrayOfColumnHeights = scope.itemCtrl.arrayOfItemColumnsHeight;
                var appendToColumn = getShortestColumn(arrayOfColumnHeights);

                el.css({
                    'top': String(arrayOfColumnHeights[appendToColumn]) + 'px',
                    'left': String(appendToColumn * 405) + 'px' //imgs are 400px always
                });

                //this is the problem area; offsetHeight doesn't properly compute all
                //the time if the img hasn't loaded already and many imgs are
                //interlaced in my collection so some get loaded right away and 
                //some don't
                arrayOfColumnHeights[appendToColumn] += el[0].offsetHeight + 10;
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

It's very simple. I have 3 columns and I'm inserting an item into the shortest column. That's really all I'm doing. I just need the offsetHeight to compute properly and I'm all set.

Comment: Okay, I posted an update. Thanks.

Comment: You can wait for <img> "load" event but be aware it does not bubble up so you have to put listener directly on image (delegation will not work)